# Is it secure to have two password managers?

Tags: password-management, keepass

For various reasons I use both Keepass 2 and Lastpass. They have 90% the same password database. Is it secure to be using and maintaining both of them? Is it secure if they both use the same password (or a very similar password)?

Answer (score 4):

By using two password managers containing identical credentials, you're effectively *increasing* the risk that the credentials get stolen. This is because there are now additional points of entry. The *security level* of all password managers combined is no more than that provided by the weakest implementation.

Thus, the recommendation is to use a single manager, which is adequately secured (a quality cipher with a strong encryption key).

Of course, you *can* use as many password managers as you like, as long as they don't contain identical entries.

See also [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/56040/43847), which is about multiple sign-in methods, but has similar reasoning.

Comment: But the two password managers have different designs and implementations to say the risk of having the passwords stolen doubles may not be accurate...isn't that presuming the attacker knows a weakness in one of the password managers?

Comment: Not if an attacker tries to guess the key by using brute-force or dictionary attacks.

Comment: There're other variables. 1)The speed at which the encrypted passwords can be decrypted given the encryption algorithm used 2)Keepass 2 database uses a key file 3)Since Lastpass is online it maybe they have certain security policies such as blocking an IP address after 5 failed login attempts. Also this is assuming the attacker already gained access to the local computer and can access keypass' database.

Comment: @Celeritas because you've put your passwords in the cloud, you must now trust that LastPass is taking appropriate steps to secure your passwords. IMO this more than doubles the potential attack vector on your information, as you must now trust the data was transmitted and stored securely. You must now also trust that LastPass has sufficient protocols in place to prevent SE attacks to try to steal your info. Last, and not least, if this info is in the States it then becomes subject to the Patriot Act.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES "IMO this more than doubles the potential attack vector" then I guess we agree you can't just say the likelihood of having passwords stolen doubles when using two password managers compared to one. " You must now also trust that LastPass has sufficient protocols in place to prevent SE attacks to try to steal your info. Last, and not least, if this info is in the States it then becomes subject to the Patriot Act" what's an SE attack? The passwords are encrypted locally so just because they're stored in US with Patriot Act doesn't matter.

Comment: @Celeritas How are you encrypting them locally?

Comment: Lastpass claims to encrypt all databases locally. They store the encrypted database on their servers, but no keys. Even if you login via their website to open your database, it should download it to your browser and then unlock it. How do you ever know that keepass doesn't upload anything? Disclaimer: I use Keepass and stopped using lastpass because of the way they mess up forms nowadays.

Comment: I edited my answer, replacing _doubles_ by _increasing_. You're correct that it depends on the implementation of each password manager.

Comment: LastPass encrypts the entries locally and uploads them to the cloud; they only store encrypted entries. However, they also store a hashed version of the user's password (to provide password recovery). So, the patriot Act is still very much of concern: When requested by the American government, LastPass must supply all stored information. An intelligence agency can then very easily attempt to crack the hashed password and use the result to unlock the credential entries.

Comment: @Steven where did you hear that the hash of the passwords are stored on the Lastpass servers? According to here only the hash of the master password used to sign in is sent to the Lastpass servers http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11361/how-does-lastpass-store-my-passwords-on-their-website

Comment: @Celeritas I meant the master password.

Comment: @Steven well how do you expect to log in if they never remember the hash of the master password?

Comment: @Celeritas That wasn't my point. The thing is: Both the encrypted credential store _and_ the hashed master password is stored on LastPass' servers. So an attacker who obtains these, just needs to break the master password to break into the credential store. So this makes LastPass less secure than KeePass in my opinion. FYI [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/), a secure web storage service, doesn't store a hash of the user's password on their servers. So there's no fallback mechanism if the password is lost or forgotten. Whether that's acceptable, is a choice their users have to make.

Comment: @Steven then how does Wuala confirm the password submitted to it is correct?

Comment: @Steven this article explains why Lastpass master passwords aren't susceptible to brute force attacks, even if the hash value is known. https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/security-options/password-iterations-pbkdf2/ (admittedly it is by Lastpass themselves)

Comment: @Celeritas I'm not entirely sure, but it _seems_ logical that some kind of identifier is stored along with the encrypted files. When a password is entered, the decrypted identifier is then (again, _probably_) checked for equality with a non-encrypted version of the identifier. If you're interested, you can read more about Wuala's security [here](http://www.wuala.com/en/learn/technology). Regarding LastPass' hash rounds: Thanks for sharing that. I guess that _if_ the number of rounds never leaves your computer, the stored hash in the cloud is useless?

Comment: @Celeritas I've found [this article](https://support.wuala.com/2013/08/wualas-encryption-explained/) that explains Wuala's encryption mechanism. In short: When authenticating, the credentials are fed through a PBKDF2 function which produces the master key. Then, a pre-installed file (the _root item_ in Wuala jargon) is downloaded and decrypted with the derived master key. If this succeeded, the Wuala client software knows you've supplied the correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I will say two things:

1. Use a different password for each manager.
2. Make sure your passwords are both memorable and strong.

With 2 managers storing nearly identical data, an attacker now has more attack vectors to work with.  This arguably reduces security in certain ways.  It does, however, increase your password recovery options.  Having backups is a good thing.

Assuming both passwords are adequately strong, and your computer is not compromised, the reduction in security should not be significant enough to matter, and the convenience and peace-of-mind you gain from using 2 managers should be worth it for most people.

I use KeepassXC and Bitwarden.  One effectively functions as a backup for the other.  Bitwarden is more convenient for browser logins, while KeepassXC is generally more secure and more flexible to use.  My Keepass vault is protected by a 37-character password, while my Bitwarden account is protected by a 44-character password.  I'm not losing any sleep over it.